# android sqlite union, how to retrive results from the tables?

Tags: android, sqlite, union

I have this SQLite query:

```
Cursor orgiCursor = orgiDb.rawQuery("select task,taskDate from meeting where exists 
(select `meeting.taskId from Task, meeting where meeting.taskId = Task.taskId and task.name='"+profName+"')
UNION  SELECT subject,date from taskDeadline where exists (select taskDeadline.taskId from taskDeadline,Task where taskDeadline.taskId=Task.taskId and Task.name='"+profName+"') union select 
specificOccassion,setDate from AnnualTask where exists (select taskId from Task,AnnualTask where Task.taskId = AnnualTask.taskId and Task.name = '"+profName+"' and AnnualTask.setDate<>'--')", null);
```

It's quite long really, but it works flawlessly on SQLite Manager. My problem is that I get an error in retrieving the data. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
try {
    if (orgiCursor != null ) {
        if (orgiCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String annualTask = orgiCursor.getString(orgiCursor.getColumnIndex("specificOccassion"));
                String annualDate = orgiCursor.getString(orgiCursor.getColumnIndex("setDate"));
                String meetingTask = orgiCursor.getString(orgiCursor.getColumnIndex("task"));
                String meetingDate = orgiCursor.getString(orgiCursor.getColumnIndex("taskDate"));
                String deadlineTask = orgiCursor.getString(orgiCursor.getColumnIndex("subject"));
                String deadlineDate = orgiCursor.getString(orgiCursor.getColumnIndex("date"));

                SearchResults sr2=new SearchResults();
                sr2.setName(meetingTask);
                sr2.settDate(meetingDate);
                results.add(sr2);

                SearchResults sr3 = new SearchResults();
                sr3.setName(deadlineTask);
                sr3.settDate(deadlineDate);
                results.add(sr3);

                SearchResults sr1 = new SearchResults();
                sr1.setName(annualTask);
                sr1.settDate(annualDate);
                Log.i("Home","added"+annualTask + " & " +annualDate);
                results.add(sr1);
            } while (orgiCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
} catch (SQLiteException se) {
    displayError1(se.toString());
    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), se.toString());
} finally {
    if (orgiDb != null) {
        orgiDb.close();
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),"orgiDB closed()");
    }
}


    return results;
```

It returns this error. :( Please help me.

```
02-12 19:28:00.809: INFO/Database(14515): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = ambiguous column name: taskId
02-12 19:28:00.849: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14515): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: ambiguous column name: taskId: , while compiling: select task,taskDate from meeting where exists (select meeting.taskId from Task, meeting where meeting.taskId = Task.taskId and task.name='Maria Ozawa')UNION  SELECT subject,date from taskDeadline where exists (select taskDeadline.taskId from taskDeadline,Task where taskDeadline.taskId=Task.taskId and Task.name='Maria Ozawa') union select specificOccassion,setDate from AnnualTask where exists (select taskId from Task,AnnualTask where Task.taskId = AnnualTask.taskId and Task.name = 'Maria Ozawa' and AnnualTask.setDate<>'--')

02-12 19:28:01.059: ERROR/Database(14515): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/orgy.organizer.home/databases/orgi' 
02-12 19:28:01.059: ERROR/Database(14515): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated... :(
So my questions are:
1. Which part of the code do I exactly need to close the connection/cursor?
2. Why does Eclipse give me this error? I tried running this same statement in SQLite Manager and it gave me flawless results.

Answer (score 0):

it seems the error is in the query, the fact it does not close the cursor is because he does not compute the query correctly i think

try to use alias when you use the attribute taskId, you use it many times and maybe it confuses the compiler

hope this helped!

Comment: Thank you. I shall try that today. :)